# custom login with form authentication

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have an asp project wish contain a login page. My problem is, i need to **configure the   `web.config` to accept my new login page**

Can you help me figure out my problem?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="myLogin.aspx" />
    </authentication>
    ....
 </system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the [Microsoft knowledge base](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240)